# Transforming 3D matrix into readable format

Tags: javascript, css, matrix

Since my knowledge about matrices is close to nil, I was looking for a helper method, that could do the conversion from matrix array to readable format.

With readable format I mean:

```
{
    translate : 
    {
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
        z : 0
    },

    rotation :
    {
        x : 0,
        y : 90,
        z : 0
    },

    skew :
    {
        x : 0,
        y : 0
    },

    scale :
    {
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
        z : 0
    }
}
```

With matrix format I mean: `matrix3d(0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)`.

I have been looking through google for such a method, but cannot seem to find it.

Is there such a method, or how could I decypher / calculate each transformation type on each available axis?

**Update:** A friend of mine has stumbled upon http://web.iitd.ac.in/~hegde/cad/lecture/L6_3dtrans.pdf, will be looking into this to try to retrieve at least something.

Comment: This article's a pretty useful explanation of matrix3D https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-function, although would take a quite a bit of effort to use this knowledge to write a conversion tool. It's worth noting as well that the order in which skew, rotate etc... are carried out is important i.e. rotation followed by skew isn't necessarily the same as skew followed by rotate, so any readable version of the matrix woudl have to make some explicit assumptions about which transformation is expected to be carried out first

Comment: Hmm, but that applies to skew and rotation, doesn't it? If so, the method could be constructed in a way that it'd accept parameters to select order of skew and rotation.

Comment: yep it could, just something to consider

Comment: Maybe this project could be helpful https://github.com/mattdesl/mat4-decompose

Answer (score 1):

It's not really easy to decompose the matrix back to the original transformations. I've managed to decompose `scale*rotate*translate` matrix.

```
function extract(m) { // supports only scale*rotate*translate matrix
    var radians = Math.PI / 180

    var sX = Math.sqrt(m[0]*m[0] + m[1]*m[1] + m[2]*m[2]),
        sY = Math.sqrt(m[4]*m[4] + m[5]*m[5] + m[6]*m[6]),
        sZ = Math.sqrt(m[8]*m[8] + m[9]*m[9] + m[10]*m[10])

    var rX = Math.atan2(-m[9]/sZ, m[10]/sZ) / radians,
        rY = Math.asin(m[8]/sZ) / radians,
        rZ = Math.atan2(-m[4]/sY, m[0]/sX) / radians

    if (m[4] === 1 || m[4] === -1) {
      rX = 0
      rY = m[4] * -Math.PI/2
      rZ = m[4] * Math.atan2(m[6]/sY, m[5]/sY) / radians
    }

    var tX = m[12]/sX,
        tY = m[13]/sX,
        tZ = m[14]/sX

    return {
      translate: [tX, tY, tZ],
      rotate: [rX, rY, rZ],
      scale: [sX, sY, sZ]
    }
}
```

But it will fail for any other transformations order.

Comment: Any idea how to return skew too?

Comment: Hey this code has `radians` as undefined variable, what would be the formula?

Comment: Added `radians` variable. You can also take a look at https://github.com/michaelvillar/dynamics.js/blob/master/src/dynamics.coffee#L766-L920. It has a more advanced decompose method

Comment: I found something interesting https://github.com/start940315/matrix/blob/master/matrix.js

Comment: Please, either read carefully, that it only supports `scale*rotate*translate`, or don't make wrong assumptions. This code is used in https://github.com/lvivski/anima/blob/master/src/math/matrix.js. And it is tested. `Matrix.decompose(Matrix.multiply(Matrix.identity(), Matrix.scale(.5, .5, .5), Matrix.rotate(30, 45, 45), Matrix.translate(100,10,5)))` gives correct values for `scale`,  `rotate` and `translate`

Comment: Alright, here is the computed style
http://s17.postimg.org/5svvzdo3z/computed_style.gif
and here is the decomposed matrix, call me blunt, but I cannot figure it out

http://s29.postimg.org/8ja9zwqhj/decomposed_matrix.gif

Comment: As mentioned above, it only supports one particular transformations order (`translate rotate scale`) http://s17.postimg.org/upcsqhn4f/Screen_Shot_2015_06_25_at_12_43_18_AM.png and then http://s17.postimg.org/bmtf3kc3y/Screen_Shot_2015_06_25_at_12_46_51_AM.jpg. You get strange values because JS uses IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic, so you have to round it a little. For more advanced decomposition, please, refer to https://github.com/michaelvillar/dynamics.js/blob/master/src/dynamics.coffee#L766-L920. It supports `skew` and `perspective` among others. Thanks.